# search users using user name and user meta in wordpress

Tags: users

I was saving the wordpress user as below:

```
  $user_data = array(
                'ID' => '',
                'user_pass' => '',
                'user_login' => $user_name,
                'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'role' => 'trainer' 
          );
$random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'course_registered',$course_registered );
wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

Presently I am using the 'WP_User_Query' method with following arguments:

```
$args = array(
            'role' => 'trainer',
            'orderby' => 'display_name',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'paged' => $paged,  
            'search'         => '*'.$trainer_name.'*',
            'search_columns' => array( 'user_login'),
            'count_total'    => true,
            'number'        => 5,
            'meta_query' => array(

                    array(
                        'key'     => 'course_registered',
                        'value'   => $course_name,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            )
        );
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

I want to search user if either by 'user name' or meta_key 'course_registered' else both. I tried the above& also searched many but didn't work any one. could anyone please help me..!

Comment: Did you try without the asterisks in `'search'` field?

Comment: @Prasad, did you figure out what the issue was?